Why is the definition of smooth altas related to transition maps and not just to smoothness of the charts of the atlas?
I am trying to understand why a $C^k$ atlas is not defined as follows:

$\tag{1}$ for every chart $(U_i,x_i)_{i\in I}$ of the atlas, $x_i$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism between $U_i$ and $x_i(U_i)$

instead of the usual definition:

$\tag{2}$ any two charts of the altas are $C^k$ compatible.

This answer says: "for a topological space $X$ it makes sense to talk about homeomorphisms and local homeomorphisms. The notion of smoothness, however, does not make sense at this stage" since "$X$ (and the $U_i$ of the charts of any $C^0$ atlas of $X$) does not have any structure".
Why is it impossible to talk about smoothness on  $X$ or for the charts of any $C^0$ atlas on it?
Could it be that the reason why definition $(1)$ is not valid is that a diffeomorphism is only defined between manifolds?

I'll take the example of the surface $S^1$. One possible  $C^0$ atlas is constructed with two charts. The first chart $x$ takes  off one point on the circle $p$, and then maps homeomorphically $S^1 \backslash\{p\}$ to $(-\pi, \pi)$. The second chart $y$ takes off another point $q$ and maps homeomorphically  $S^1 \backslash \{q\}$ to, say, $(0,2\pi)$. In this case $y\circ x^{-1}$ goes from $(-\pi,0)\cup (0,\pi)$ to $(0,\pi) \cup (\pi, 2\pi)$ and is defined by  the identity $Id$ over $(0,\pi)$ and by $Id + 2\pi$ over $(-\pi,0)$. We can claim that $x$ and $y$ are $C^{\infty}$ compatible. Hence the atlas above-mentioned is $C^{\infty}$, according to definition $(2)$.
But couldn't have we remarked that $x$ and $y$ (which are equal to $t \mapsto e^{it}$) are $C^{\infty}$ ?
Thanks in advance.

Without using any charts, what's the definition of a smooth function $f: U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

$x_i$ pushes the (relatively) open sets of $U_i$ to "freshly minted" open sets of $X$ (and the atlas gives a sufficient generating set for all the open sets of $X$).  How does one define continuous (much less diffeomorphism) when one doesn't know which are the open sets (yet)?  (After applying all the $x_i$, we get "continuous" for free because the only open sets are the ones the $x_i$ create, so there cannot be a witness to discontinuity.  But maybe the $x_i$ aren't pairwise compatible...)

When you say

But couldn't have we remarked that $x$ and $y$ (which are equal to $t\to e^{it}$) are $C^\infty$?

You are already implicitly giving (smooth) coordinates to $S^1$. The space $S^1$ is merely a topological space, with no additional structure. It doesn't make sense to say these maps are "equal to $t\to e^{it}$" without first introducting a parameterization of the circle---in this case, you are implicitly working with the parameterization given by the exponential map.
Think of $S^1$ purely abstractly, not as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$. How are you defining $e^{it}$? You won't be able to do this without choosing (smooth) coordinates somehow, which was the whole point of the definition.
The same goes for more general spaces. Before being given an atlas, manifolds are just abstract topological spaces, and the introduction of a system of charts is essentially the same thing as saying what it means for functions to be smooth in this abstract setting.
As we saw in the $S^1$ example, saying what it means to be smooth is equivalent to giving the space a (local) parameterization by $\mathbb{R}^n$ (in the $S^1$ case, by $e^{it}$), and then declaring this parameterization to be smooth. Once that parameterization is fixed, it can be used to define smoothness for other maps (as you have demonstrated). When you unwrap all of this, you're left with the standard definition of an atlas.

I got your argument about the parameterization of $e^{it}$. But then, I think it raises the question of whether there is any way of constructing a homeomorphism explicitly (when they say $(x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{(x,y,z)}{max(|x|,|y|,|z|)}$ is the homeomorphism that maps $S^2$ to the unit cube, it isn't right since $(x,y,z)$ is ill-defined)

I wouldn't say that $(x,y,z)$ in your example isn't well-defined, just that it presumes an embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is a perfectly valid definition of $S^2$). However, To assume these coordinate functions are smooth is tantamount to assuming a particular smooth structure on $S^2$ which it does not a priori have.

I see something a bit confusing when you say "think of $S^1$ purely abstractly, not as a subspace of $\mathbb C$" and on the other hand "$S^2$ is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$" (which I might apply to $S^1$, by saying "$S^1$ is embbeded in $\mathbb C$"). I'm a bit lost.

It is perfectly valid to think of/represent the sphere as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or $S^1$ in $\mathbb{C}$. But doing so tricks us into thinking that the coordinate functions (or exponential function) can be considered "smooth" without reference to a smooth structure on $S^2$. Thinking of these objects abstractly does not tempt us into thinking these "obvious" functions are smooth (and in fact reveals that you need a system of coordinates in order to even define them). As soon as you say "let us represent my space using numbers" you are choosing coordinates, and thereby a smooth structure.

Also I didn't quite get why we "declare" the parametrization ($e^{it}$)to be smooth. Isn't differentiability a property that can be showed (instead of being "declared")?

Differentiability (and hence smoothness) is defined in a usual calculus class only for maps between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. To ask whether the map $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ is smooth is a completely different ball game, since $S^1$ is not $\mathbb{R}$. You have to say what it means for a map on or to $S^1$ to be smooth. You do this by deciding which abstract open sets in $S^1$ are diffeomorphic to open sets in $mathbb{R}$, or in other words, you  declare these homeomorphisms to be smooth. This choice/declaration is exactly what it means to give $S^1$ a smooth structure.

Got it! Now, on a more casual level, your undergraduate writings seem very interesting (especially your book on Group Theory)!
